# SQLite Select all rows and add to ListView Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add each row retrieved from database to the list view here's what I have done so far.

code from activity class

```
    private void getList() {
    list.add(dbms.selectAllFromRatings());
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StationListView.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

// code from databaseHelper class

```
    public String selectAllFromRatings() {
    String selectAllQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + RATING_TABLE_NAME ;
            SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(selectAllQuery, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stationName1"));
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please describe your question.

Comment: what is happening now? what is your exact problem?

Comment: No errors, but can not see any result either, even after adding so many records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way you're only getting one element. You need to return a `List`. Loop through the `Cursor` adding each element in order until there are no more elements and close it when finished. For example:

```
private void getList() {
    List<String> list = dbms.selectAllFromRatings();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StationListView.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

// Since getList() is private, this method should also be private
private List<String> selectAllFromRatings() {
    String selectAllQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + RATING_TABLE_NAME;         
    SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(selectAllQuery, null);
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stationName1")));
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that I did not test this, but it should give you the idea on how to loop through the Cursor results.

Comment: I want to print 1 row in each list item and thats what i'm struggling with

Comment: This should do precisely that, what problem you're having with the code I posted?

Comment: I want to get all column values not just stationName1

Comment: That has nothing to do with your original question which was about rows. Anyway, if you want to combine other columns, just get them like you're doing with stationName1, format as you like and then add the formatted string to the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public List<StringBuffer> selectAllFromRatings() {
    String selectAllQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + RATING_TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getReadableDatabase();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(selectAllQuery, null);
    final List<StringBuffer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            buffer.append("Review ID: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Station Name: " + c
                    .getString(1) + "\n" + "WIFI RATING: " + c.getString(2) + "TOILETS" + c
                            .getString(3));

            list.add(buffer);
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```